# On Profit and loss

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A dishonest dealer marks his goods $20\%$ above the cost price. He gives a discount of $10\%$ to the customer on the marked price and makes a profit by using a false weight of $900$ gms in place of $1$ kg while buying or selling. Find the percentage profit earned by the shopkeeper.

I do tried this problem but am not quite there,hints are welcome :-)

Answer (score 3):

The dealer doesn't actually give his customer a discount.  He charges 90% of the price for 90% of the product.  Thus he still makes a 20% profit over the supplier price. Let $C$ be the supplier price for 1 kg of product. The dealer then gets 1.1kg for the price $C$ or 1kg for $10\over{11}$$C$.  He sells this 1kg for $1.2C$.  The profit margin is $1.2C$-$10\over{11}$$C$ divided by the dealer price, $10\over{11}$$C$, which I calculate to be 32%.

Here I have assumed the "cost price" is the supplier price, $C$.  If you assume the cost price is what the dishonest dealer actually pays his supplier, you will get a different answer still.

Comment: The dealer uses false weight in both buying and selling,so he buys $1100$ gm and sells $900$ gms.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: 
Let when buying--
1100 gm at Rs. 1000 
when selling--
900 gm at Rs. 1080 [20% mark up & 10% discount]
so, the selling price of 1100 gm
=Rs. (1080*1100)/900
=Rs. 1320
Profit%= (320*100)/1000= 32%

Comment: Welcome to the site. MathJaX formatting is encouraged, to improve readability, and would really help here,